# Inconsistency between TRUE and FALSE constant definitions in PHP

Tags: php, casting

Sometimes I bang my head into the wall, because of this.

```
var_dump(ord(true), ord(false));
```

gives:

> int(49)
>   int(0)

So TRUE is converted into ASCII code 49 - number 1, and FALSE to ASCII code 0 (zero byte). **Why such inconsistency in TRUE/FALSE conversions into a string?** Why FALSE can't be converted into ASCII code 48 - number 0 where integer context is expected (because TRUE is '1')?

The biggest problem from such definitions is that if you store Boolean values in some variables which you later save in the database - then TRUE is stored as '1' and FALSE as '' - an empty string. So before storing in database you need to cast to integer `(int)($bool_variable)`. Given that PHP supports full automatic type-casting, the need to perform a **manual** casting in some scenario(s) is very frustrating and a bit stupid (either ALL types should be interchangeable or user must perform casting itself between all types).

Any ideas?

Comment: I've edited and expanded my answer below to address some of the confusion which I think is happening here, and include one possible answer to "why" this is the case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It inherently doesn't make sense to ask for the `ord` of a `bool`. `ord` expects a string, so casts any input to a string. `true` casts to `'1'`, and `false` casts to `''`. The `ord` of `'1'` is `49`, and the `ord` of an empty string is `0`.

That doesn't mean that `true` and `false` are *defined* as such. `true` is defined as `true` and `false` is defined as `false`. It's merely the type casting rules that you're stumbling over (and yes, they're arguably arcane). Most databases support native boolean types, or their PHP database API will convert PHP booleans to the database's equivalent, as long as you use the API correctly.

As for *why* those casting rules exist:

> A boolean `TRUE` value is converted to the string `"1"`. Boolean `FALSE` is converted to `""` (the empty string). This allows conversion back and forth between boolean and string values.
>
> https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.casting

No, it doesn't make any more sense than this.

Comment: Sorry for a reply, but this doesn't answer my question, I know that ord() expects a string. Question is - **Why PHP casts FALSE to '' and not to '0' ?** It seems that these casting rules are chosen so that life of PHP interpreter developer whould be easier, and not to the PHP user

Comment: Because PHP, that's why. I tried to encapsulate that in my terse "arguably arcane". Because an empty string converted back to a boolean is `false`, so it roundtrips nicely; but then again, so would `'0'`, which is also *falsey*. Soooo… go ask Rasmus.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas If you didn't want answers to discuss `ord`, you shouldn't have mentioned it in your question; it's really got nothing to do with anything - `false` is never "converted to ASCII code 0".

Comment: @IMSoP your opinion contadicts to deceze. If false is never converted to "\0" and is never defined as `\0` (deceze opinion) - then what is left ? :-) I don't know how to phrase question correctly (you are wellcome to edit it), but probably as deceze said- I wanted to ask Rasmus why he could't re-define FALSE value dynamically by variable type context, like `if (is_string($var)) define(FALSE, "\0") else define(FALSE, 0)` :-)

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas There is no `\0`. `(string)false` is `''`, an empty string.

Comment: @IMSoP Doesn't change anything `if (is_string($var)) define(FALSE, '') else define(FALSE, 0)`. And BTW in C an empty string is defined as first byte equaling to zero byte \0, and because PHP is implemented in C - that makes sense.

Comment: @Agnius I don't know what your expectations are. Perhaps that `false` is a preprocessor directive/constant which *actually* has some underlying value? Well, it does not. `false` is of type `boolean` and its value is `false`, not any other value. However it is implemented in the underlying C is irrelevant.

Comment: @deceze I already expressed my question - I want to know why FALSE is defined  as '' and not as '0' in string contexts. What are main reasons of such choice ? The only one I can think of is, in the context where some built-in returns 0 or 1 or FALSE (in failure) - you can catch an error is something bad has happened. If in that scenario FALSE would mean '0' - this error would be ignored in relation to outcome reporting to the user. Now that is the answer type i was looking for.

Comment: @Agnius I'll repeat: `false` is _not_ ***defined*** as `''`. `false` is of type `boolean` with the value `false`. It's a "singleton" value. This is not C. This is PHP. It works by PHP rules. In PHP rules, `boolean` values are of their own type and equal their own value. *Type juggling* rules have been defined between PHP's types, such that converting the boolean value `true` to a string yields `'1'`, and for `false` yields `''`. It is defined as such because that's how it's defined because that's what Rasmus has decided on some cold night many moons ago. There is no more explanation than this.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas "Why" is always a tricky question to answer about a programming language with 25 years of history. We might be able to come up with scenarios where it's useful; we might be able to point to other languages the choice was borrowed from; but we might have to say "it just is". Either way, it would have nothing to do with `ord()`, or `'\0`, or the fact that your particular database code would be easier if it was `'0'`.

Comment: @IMSoP In the case of PHP, I'd pretty much always blame it on a lack of experience with language design, and now it *simply is* as you put it, and that's that.

Comment: @deceze I think that's *slightly* unfair. Some things were just mistakes, but many were borrowed from other languages - e.g. Perl, or even C. In this case, Perl does indeed have the same behaviour (try `perl -e 'print 1==1;'` and `perl -e 'print 1==2;'`); which of course begs the question - you can always keep asking "why", but will rarely get a good answer.

Comment: @IMSoP Fair enough, though arguably there was no need to copy from Perl and he could've created something more consistent. Either way, I totally agree with you that asking "why" is useless. I share OP's feelings that the behaviour isn't exactly elegant, but discussing it won't change it either.

Answer (score 4):

Part of your confusion is that `ord` is simply not the right function to use here - it is not a casting function, and not a debugging function that accepts any type. It is a function which expects a string, and returns an int, so PHP has to first cast the boolean to a string, and then run the function.

Note that PHP **does not** convert `false` to an ASCII NUL byte (0). That's just an artefact of you using `ord()` outside of its purpose: you passed an empty string, and asked "what's the first byte of this string?" Arguably, it should have given you an error, but in this case, it decided to give you `0`.

A better test would be using `var_dump`, which is intended for inspecting PHP values:

```
var_dump(true); // bool(true)
var_dump(false); // bool(false)
var_dump((string)true); // string(1) "1"
var_dump((string)false); // string(0) ""
```

If you want to cast a boolean to a chosen representation, the best approach is just to use the ternary operator:

```php
$bitAsInt = $booleanValue ? 1 : 0;
$bitAsString = $booleanValue ? '1' : '0';
$booleanKeyword = $booleanValue ? 'true' : 'false';
$boolString = $booleanValue ? "'t'" : "'f'";
```

All of the above would be appropriate for some database systems in some contexts, and serve as a good explanation why `(string)$booleanValue` can't just give you the right thing every time.

There are some other scenarios where `(string)false` giving an empty string is the most useful, and that's what PHP has decided on. That is:

```
(string)$booleanValue === ($booleanValue ? '1' : '')
```

There are always many answers to "why". For historical context, this was likely inspired by Perl (which was popular for web programming at the time of PHP's creation) - although it doesn't have a boolean type as such, it does exhibit similar casting behaviour:

```perl
print ( 1==1 ); # true as string, gives '1'
print ( 1==2 ); # false as string, gives ''
print 0 + ( 1==1 ); # true as int, gives 1
print 0 + ( 1==2 ); # false as int, gives 0
```

Answer (score -1):

An empty string is considered by php as false. Whether it's read from a database or not.

Are you trying to solve a database query problem?

Comment: It is not an explanation. PHP designers could handle this situation like so `if (is_string($var)) define(FALSE, "\0") else define(FALSE, 0)` in boolean comparisons context of $var. So it's seems like a design choice for making PHP interpreter more simple (and not for making a simple life for a PHP user)

Comment: I don't see how it makes like more difficult for the php user. PHP reads and writes values the same way. What specific issue are you having?

Comment: I don't have any specific issue (I already solved my problem), my question was more about **"why"** - historical reasons of one or another PHP interpreter design decisions ...

Comment: I think it's syntactic sugar. You can do things like if($variable){ } and if variable is 0 or "" which to non programmers would seem logical, it works as expected.

Comment: It has nothing to do with syntactic sugar. Seems you don't understand the question. There are **several** ways how `false` can be casted to a string. In this case question arises - which casting rule interpreter should apply and why ? The only explanations I've got are: 1. It's just a matter of taste of PHP interpreter developer 2. Because it was similarly implemented in Perl and PHP copied that idea without thinking much